# How to style <li>s inside <ul> as a table with custom height?

Tags: css, css-tables

I'm trying to create a bar graph in html and css but I'm having problems with `<li>` style.
I have an undefined list of bars with different heights, I want them to have an auto width to fit the `<ul>` horizontally automatically.
If I set a `display: table-cell` to the `<li>s` they will will auto fit horizontally but the custom height won't apply (they will spread to the full height of `ul`, I think that's how it's supposed to work) and won't respect left/right margins.

So how do I:

1. auto fit the width of the `<li>s` with the possibility to apply padding/margin
2. use custom heights
3. align them to the bottom

If I use `float: left` they will show up correctly but then I must set width manually which is impossible without using decimal spacing or JavaScript.

```
<ul id="bars">
<li style='height:87%'></li>
<li style='height:100%'></li>
<li style='height:79%'></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#bars {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: table;

}

#bars li {
    display: table-cell;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0 1px 2px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0 1px 2px;
    background:  #65c2e8;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a bar chart as a table.  Each bar is created using `:before` pseudo-element.  It could have been more efficient to assign height and background color for each bar in HTML and then use them in CSS using `attr()` function.  Right now, the `attr()` function implementation is very limited.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/77tZP/.  Only changing of table dimensions is necessary to resize the visual.  For the rest of the elements, I've used percentages.

HTML:

```
<ul id="bars">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
*, :before, :after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: 10px;
}

ul {
    outline: 1px solid #aaa;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: table;
    height: 100px;
    width: 70px;
    padding: 10px 3px 3px;
}

ul > li {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

ul > li:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 5%;
    background-clip: content-box;
    background-color: red;
    height: 87%;
}

ul > li:nth-of-type(2):before {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
}

ul > li:nth-of-type(3):before {
    background-color: purple;
    height: 79%;
}
```

Comment: That works but the method cannot work for dynamic data since I can't set "li:nth-of-type(x):before" dynamically (I can but it's a mess and unpractical). So I tried the same thing using html (div) inside the li but it won't work the same way, the padding is not respected at all. http://jsfiddle.net/a8ctj/ the bar won't space and there's an odd offset on some :|

Comment: That's because you have 83 bars.  If each bar takes less than 10px, then 5% of 10px is 0.5px, which is not going to work.  So, here's a fiddle that uses left and right padding of 25% and it works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Rs425/.  Or, just use fixed padding.  Or, set the width on divs and set `text-align: center` on list items: http://jsfiddle.net/Dq8XX/.  Also, even in my original solution I used `vertical-align: bottom` on both the list item and its child div.

Comment: Thanks! Does it work for you on FF? It shows up blank for me, but works on Chrome.

Comment: If I wanted to set margin-right that would be impossible right? The padding destroys the box/shadow link. Sew this http://jsfiddle.net/Rs425/2/

Comment: Solved by using border-spacing even though it can't take percentages.

Answer (score 1):

create an element inside the li and give THAT the height value like so:

```
<ul class="bars">
  <li>
    <div style="height:80%;">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

edit: also add: vertical-align:bottom for the li's